What is maximum voltage across overcurrent limit resistors of ISL70002SEH voltage regulator?
I am trying to determine the maximum voltage across the OCx and OCSSx resistors shown below:

The datasheet says the following:

It seems it is saying that the maximum voltage across ROCx is 60V.
Also when I simplify the ROCSSx equation, I get:
IOCSSx = 60/ROCSSx + 60/ROCx
Which seems to me to further indicate the voltage at OCA to be 60V.
That seems strange to me, since AVDD is at 5.5V maximum.
Can anyone explain to me what I am missing? Thank you.

Maximum voltage is ~ 5 V. Note that the resistors formulas are noted in kOhm ... So, it does not indicates that voltage should be "60 V".

There are some incorrect assumptions being made here -- it may help to understand how these sorts of connections are made internally.
Typically, a reference voltage is set on the pin, and current is drawn through a resistor.  This current is converted back into a voltage internally, then back into a current at the main output.
For example, a buck converter might use an adjustable peak current limit circuit like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The CLK oscillator itself might be timed in a similar way, for example the TL494's oscillator uses a common-base structure, then current mirrors, to charge the timing capacitor; the resistor attached to the IC pin (Q1 emitter) thus dictates the charging slope.
An inverse connection can also be used.  Instead of applying a fixed voltage to Q1 base, a differential amplifier might copy R3's voltage drop over to Q1-E, now as a ground-referenced voltage; an op-amp is used to control V(Q1-B) such that this voltage is set, and the corresponding collector current tells how much current the user has programmed the device to pass, or what have you.
Note that all these ratios (current mirrors, relative resistor values) can be controlled internally, so that a, whatever, 1A, 10A, etc. regulator can be programmed with a small current, fractional mA perhaps; the current or voltage is multiplied internally, or related by other ratios and functions, to give the desired result overall.  The corresponding design equations can have all range of constants in them, and according to dimensional analysis, those constants may have dimensions of voltage or current -- but they are just constants, parameters resulting from working through all these ratios, and are not, in general, real currents or voltages inside the device.
More complicated systems can be used, of course.  For example, converting the current into a voltage, storing the voltage on a capacitor, and then disabling the resistor pin to save on bias current -- a sample-and-hold function.  Or using an analog-digital converter (ADC) then storing the value as digits in a register.
Mind, I don't know at a glance if this is precisely what's being done here, but exact retails aren't so important; what's important is that there's some V(I) relationship being measured at the pin, and maybe it's being done continuously, maybe once in a while, maybe just once ever (at startup), but what you're setting with the resistor is the ratio of voltage to current.  The actual values of voltage or current at the pin, can be quite small, or even variable, and doing this at signal levels (a few volts say) is very normal.

The main equation has units of kohm.
For the equation to balance the currents must be in mA.
60 is just a scaling factor, probably based on the nominal kohm value of an internal resistor.
The second equation sets a 10 time overload limit based on a 60 kohm reference resistor.
